# Suricata rule to block particular website question

Tags: ids, kali-linux

I am writing rule for suricata which is going to block the possibility to enter one of the website for example xyz.com (instead of facebook, because with facebook there are some problems).

I am doing this in the way like this:

```
drop tcp any any -> any any (msg:"facebook is blocked"; content:"facebook.com"; http_header; nocase; classtype:policy-violation; sid:1;)
```

What I want to do is to block just the website. And in the way I do now, the rule is also blocking for example the requests to google which contain phrase "facebook".

May anyone advise me how I should change my rule ? I was thinking to limit just to the ip addresses of particular website, but it is not working properly or I do not know how to do it properly in rule. Is enough to change "any" in the beggining of rule for ip address of facebook ? But some servers have more than one IP addresses. How I can get the ip address of facebook inside rule ?

edit:

Also one more question is how I can change the string "abc" for "***" inside the rule ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `http_header` keyword, use the `http_host` keyword. It will specifically match against the "Host" header.

For wildcard matching you should have a look at PCRE: 
[Suricata User Guide » Suricata Rules » Payload keywords » pcre (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)](https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Pcre_%28Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions%29)